# Comb Box adds and/or deletes a text box/combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Combo Box inside a Group Box. The Combo Box has 2 items. Namely "Shoes" and "Shirts". What I'm trying to do is.. On runtime, when I pick Shirts, the event will add a Combo Box. But when I pick Shoes, it will add a Text Box.

I have managed to make it work when I pick once. (eg. I picked Shirts first. It added a Combo Box) but after picking again the added combo box wont be removed and the text box isn't visible (eg. after picking Shirts. I picked Shoes. the combo box was still there and text box was nowhere to be found)

I'm using this code.

```
    Dim SML As New ComboBox

    If ComboBox2.Text = "Shirts" Then
        SML.Size = New Size(35, 20)
        SML.Location = New Point(103, 158) 'set the position according to your layout
        SML.Items.Add("S")
        SML.Items.Add("M")
        SML.Items.Add("L")

        SML.Visible = True
        SML.Name = "A"

        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(SML) 'add it to form's control collection.
        GroupBox1.Refresh() 'If in panel etc. change Me with that control.


    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Shoes"  Then
        GroupBox1.Controls.Remove(SML)
        GroupBox1.Refresh()
        TextBox5.Enabled = True

    Else
        TextBox5.Enabled = False
    End If
```

Comment: Is this code handled by the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? Where do you declare, instantiate and add the infamous `TextBox` of yours? All I see is the `ComboBox`. If the selected text is `Shoes`, do you really expect `GroupBox1` to contain the newly created (not added) `ComboBox`?

Comment: why not simply hide the control instead of removing it?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Yes it is in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. I already added the textbox in the form. I expect the `GroupBox1` to add and remove either the `Combo Box` or the `Text Box` depending on the Selected index.

Comment: @Icepickle Do you mean Hide the `text box` or `combo box` depending on the selected index?

Comment: Yes, hiding or showing it, then there is no need to remove it from the control, and worry about the replacing

Comment: @icepickle well this would do.. Thanks! easier to code..